# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: net/lingala/zip4j/core/HeaderReader.class

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

При обновлении gradle-plugin появилась такая ошибка

> Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry:
>   net/lingala/zip4j/core/HeaderReader.class

В версии gradle-plugin 1.3.1 всё нормально. Начиная с версии 1.5.0 уже не работает.

Я пробовал но не помогло:

1. В терминале запускать "./gradlew clean"
2. Invalidate cache and restart
3. Clean and rebuild project

Файл build-gradle
    android {

```
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
        applicationId "ru.statistic"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1451145152
        versionName "1.1.1.1"
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile project(':MPChartLib')
    compile('de.psdev.licensesdialog:licensesdialog:1.6.0') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }

    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.github.andkulikov:transitions-everywhere:1.2.2'
    compile 'se.emilsjolander:stickylistheaders:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.9.0.0'
    compile 'com.pnikosis:materialish-progress:1.2'
    compile 'me.relex:circleindicator:1.1.3@aar'
    compile 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zbar:1.9'
}
```

Библиотека zip4j_1.3.2.jar находится в папке libs. Даже если удалить его добавить в gradle

> compile group: 'net.lingala.zip4j', name: 'zip4j', version: '1.3.2'

ничего не меняется.

Может кто-нибудь подсказать что делать?

Если запускать приложение в эмуляторе с андроидом 5.1, то ошибки почему то нет. А если с андроид 4.4 то уже ошибка.

Comment: Попробуйте обновить гредл до 2.14 версии и заодно андроид студию до 2.2 хотя бы. Ну или вручную убирайте лишние зависимости через exclude

Comment: Пробовал и 2.14 и бета версию 2.2, не помогло. Начиная 1.5.0 не работает. В изменениях плагина 1.5.0 [написано](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html) "Added a new Transform API". У меня в коде ошибки как раз есть "com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException". Только мне непонятно что делать и как исправить.

Comment: Проблема в том что 2 зависимости содержат внутри себя одно и тоже,   нужно оставить в 1 а в остальных отключить либа удалив из jar  с помощью любого архиватора или через exclude. Ну или ждём полного ответа. Тема актуальная,  но чуть подправьте вопрос, он не зависит от конкретного имени проблемного пакета.

Comment: не содержат одно и тоже, а ссылаются на запись одного и того же класса, что и выдает duplicate. 
Я наоборот считаю что на вопрос очень сложно дать конкретный ответ, который решит проблему, тут можно и действительно просто перебрать ссылки в gradle, чтоб встряхнуть зависимости, а может просто  в какой-то из lib идет работа с этим классом автономно и нужно  перебирать их, может где-то просто в проекте есть вложка дублированная и один и тот же компонент пинает это класс дважды.И не факт что дважды _)